# Two CSS triangle classes not working together

Tags: html, css

```css
.arrow-top {
 position: relative;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ded6d6;
}
.arrow-top:after, .arrow-top:before {
 top: 0%;
 left: 5%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-top:after {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-top-color: #fff;
 border-width: 15px;
 margin-left: -15px;
}
.arrow-top:before {
 border-color: rgba(222, 214, 214, 0);
 border-top-color: #ded6d6;
 border-width: 16px;
 margin-left: -16px;
}
.arrow-bot {
 position: relative;
 background: #f0e8ce;
 border: 1px solid #ded6d6;
}
.arrow-bot:after, .arrow-bot:before {
 top: 100%;
 left: 5%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 margin-top: -1px;
}

.arrow-bot:after {
 border-color: rgba(240, 232, 206, 0);
 border-top-color: #f0e8ce;
 border-width: 15px;
 margin-left: -15px;
}
.arrow-bot:before {
 border-color: rgba(222, 214, 214, 0);
 border-top-color: #ded6d6;
 border-width: 16px;
 margin-left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-bot arrow-top" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;">
</div>
```

Can someone explain, why `arrow-top` and `arrow-bottom` are not working together, but seperately they work fine. Also, **how do I make them work together on a container or achieve same effect**?
Arrows generator: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because you seem to be applying two different styles to the same object. The CSS will usually take the last rule you give it, but essentially, you can't apply two rules to the same element. In order to do what you would like, you need to have two separate divs in which you apply styles to both!

```
<style>
// CSS Code from the Question
</style>
<div class="arrow-top></div><div class="arrow-bottom"></div>
```

In order to put them in a container, you would surround the divs in another div, and give a class. Then call this something and in the CSS, declare the position of your container and reposition the divs wherever you need them to be.

Hope this helps